# Does Google Calendar API support FREQ=HOURLY in Recurrence Rule?

Tags: google-calendar-api, rrule

Trying to block conference rooms calendars for example every 3 hours for 2 hours during weekdays from a certain date to another from 9am to 5pm cst.

No matter what I try in the recurrence rule, when I use `FEQ=HOURLY`, I get an `Invalid recurrence rule` error. Which leads me to believe that maybe Google Calendar API does not support the parameter.

I couldn't find anything saying so in the following documentations:

- https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/events-calendars#recurrence_rule
- https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#recurrence

Can anyone confirm?

Here are the recurrence rules I've tried with FREQ=HOURLY:

1. `RRULE:FREQ=HOURLY;INTERVAL=3;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR;BYHOUR=9,12,15;UNTIL={{date-time}}`
2. `RRULE:FREQ=HOURLY;INTERVAL=3;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR;BYHOUR=9,12,15`
3. `RRULE:FREQ=HOURLY;INTERVAL=3;UNTIL={{date-time}}`

This works for example but doesn't accomplish what I want to do:

`RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR;UNTIL={{date-time}}`

I could create the events per time (meaning run the rule that works above for 9am, then again for 12pm, and again for 3pm) but having all those events part of the recurrence would simplify things for us if we wanted to modify them quickly and could be done by other business units.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Google Calendar does not support hourly recurrences

- You can easily verify it by creating a recurrent event from the Google Calenar UI.
- As you will see, the only possible recurrence intervals are `day`, `week`, `month` and `year`.
- Unfortunately, features that are not supported by Google products from the UI, will not be supported by the respective API either

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate your reply ziganotschka!